# Rspec for controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec2

```
def finding
  if params[:called_by] == ‘ATTACHMENT’
    Dir.mkdir('tmp/tmp_pdf') unless File.exists?('tmp/tmp_pdf')
    name = params[:ticket_attachment].original_filename
 end 
end
```

Above is my controller method.

```
it 'called attachment' do
    get :notifications, params: { id: users.user_id, called_by:'ATTACHMENT'}
    expect(response).to render_template(:finding)
```

end

Above is my Spec for the Controller method.

on Running my spec , i am getting the error as

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass
```

Looking forward for the solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: it is because `params[:ticket_attachment]` is nil, you can try print it out and see in terminal value. just add `puts "\n\n Here - " + params[:ticket_attachment]` before you assign to `name`

Comment: you send `params: { id: users.user_id, called_by:'ATTACHMENT'}` and do not include `:ticket_attachment` in your params in the spec, that is why it is `nil`

Comment: how is the progress?

Comment: okay @Hatik will check